# unable to send a excel file by attaching Contract standard object

Tags: singleemailmessage, contracts

want to send a excel file by attaching Contract standard object  some fields in a file as attachment and email

Comment: Can you go into more detail?  It sounds like you may want a drawloop or conga solution, but I need more info.